# "Open with difftool" doesn't do anything

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have a file with local changes. I right-click and select "Open with difftool" from Git Extensions and nothing happens. Difftool opens fine for some other files. This file is not shown neither in the Commit window and in `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

I had my file marked with `--skip-worktree`. To fix, run the following (mind the case in the `filepath`):

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <filepath>
```

Git GUI allows adding custom commands. I now have one command to --skip-worktree and the other to revert this change.